# why does my node js app serving same data to two devices?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http

I'm pretty new to node js and I'm trying to write a very basic API, with which I can post data on to MongoDB and retrieve from it.

However, when I run the server, it runs on `localhost:3000` and I can access, it from my other devices on `192.168.0.8:3000`. I can request for data using this endpoint `localhost:3000/api/v1/limit=2` to get 2 documents from MongoDB. The problem is when I request data from my other PC using `192.168.0.8:3000/api/v1?limit=6` and simultaneously request this URL `localhost:3000/api/v1?limit=2` on the main PC, both the browsers show JSON data with 6 documents instead of 6 and 2 and sometimes they show 2 documents instead of 6 and 2.

I'm not using express, I'm just using http module to create the server.

Here is my code, that handles the requests:

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const CircularJSON = require('circular-json')
PORT = 3000;

let uri="mongodb+srv://testdb:<password>@cluster0.fbttm.mongodb.net/<databasename>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

let MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;


let server = http.createServer((req, res)=>{
    if(req.url=='/' && req.method=='GET'){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.writeHead(200, "OK");
        let d = {"res":"welcome to lootcart api. go to api/v1/ to fetch the data"};
        res.write(JSON.stringify(d));
        res.end();
    }
    else if(req.url == '/' && req.method == 'POST'){
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        res.writeHead(403, "Access Forbidden");
        let d = {"res":"Acess Denied"};
        res.write(JSON.stringify(d));
        res.end();
    }
    else{
        if(req.method=='POST'){
            p = "https://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1?";
            req.on('data', (chunk)=>{
                p += chunk.toString();
                console.log(p)
            })
            const queryObj = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
            console.log("Inserting into database...");
            console.log(queryObj);
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.writeHead(200, "OK");
    
            MongoClient.connect(uri, {useUnifiedTopology:true}, async (err, db)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else{
                    let dbo = db.db('jaychandra');
                    dbo.collection('lootcart').insertOne(queryObj, (err, result)=>{
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                        else{
                            res.write('{"res":"OK"}');
                            res.end();
                            db.close();
                            console.log("Done");
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
    
        }
        else{
            const queryObj = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
            console.log("Retrieving from database...");
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.writeHead(200, "OK");
            //d = {"res":"here is your data"};
            lim = parseInt(queryObj.limit);

            MongoClient.connect(uri, {useUnifiedTopology:true}, (err, db)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                else{
                    let dbo = db.db('jaychandra');
                    const collection = dbo.collection('lootcart');
                    collection.find({}).limit(lim).toArray().then((ans)=>{
                        res.write(JSON.stringify(ans));
                        res.end()
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }

})

server.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log(`Listening at port ${PORT}`);
})
```

What am I doing wrong? and How do I fix this? any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: you may need to include more code, esp. around where the HTTP server is created and the callback function used

Comment: @Joe just added the whole code.

Comment: Highly suspicious of connecting all the time.